# Remote Desktop Slower Connecting Times Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, networking, remote-desktop

I have setup an old computer to be used as a kind of server with Windows 10 Pro installed.

I have connected it with an ethernet cable and is on the same network as the computer that I am using for connecting it to.

I have set up the RDP as to always be logged in and never shut down/sleep. I have a program running that needs to be on 24/7. The user does not log out and it looks like it is working.

However, I am experiencing some slow down after 3 days of being on. The connecting process that would finish almost instantly now takes up to 30 seconds to connect with my remote machine.

Does anybody know how this is happening and is there a way to fix it? I guess something is getting cached and that it will only get worse.
RDP: Windows 10 Pro

Main PC: Windows 10 Home

Comment: There might be some resource leak that is slowing things down. Leaks are very hard to analyze and fix, so the best workaround is to reboot periodically.